# Using a Contextual filter on a webform

Tags: 7, views

I have a View that creates a tabbed block with different content types shown in the different tabs. I now want to add a Webform as another tab.

Normally I would add the webform in under the Filter settings and the Webform:Body as the field.

The problem in this case is that I am also using a Contextual Filter to filter the content types depending on the page the user is on. As the webform doesn't have a Content:X field like the other types do, the filter just filters out the webform.

I've got as far as creating an attachment for the view, and created a Contextual Filter based on the Webform: Node with the default value set to 'Raw data from URL' and I *think* the next step is to create a custom PHP Code validator to match the argument from the URL with a specific webform NID... but I can't seem to find a decent example of what this should look like.

I'm thinking of something simple like:

```
$ct1_forms = array(100, 110, 120);
$ct2_forms = array(200, 210, 220);
return ($argument == 'content_type_1' and in_array(NID, ct1_forms)
    or ($argument == 'content_type_2' and in_array(NID, ct2_forms)
```

The main thing I don't understand is how to reference the Webform: Node field in the validator.

Am I barking up the wrong tree, is there another better way of doing this,
or can someone show me how to create the validator correctly?